# Trying to understand the Range collection in Scala and why errors arise upon assigning the data type in Scala v2.13 as opposed to v2.11

Tags: scala

I am taking a basic Scala training offered here: https://www.lynda.com/Scala-tutorials/Scala-Essential-Training-Data-Science/559182-2.html and on an introductory section where the instructor is introducing collections, he issues these commands in the REPL (using Scala v2.11):

```
scala> val myRange = 1 to 10
myRange: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> val myRange2 : Range = new Range(1, 101, 2)
myRange2: Range = Range(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99)
```

The inferred type becomes a type of object: `scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive` and the explicitly typed one is just: `Range`.

Furthermore, in version 2.13 of Scala (the current version I had installed before I rolled back to the instructors version), the same commands result in:

```
scala> val myRange = 1 to 10
myRange: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range 1 to 10

scala> val myRange2 : Range = new Range(1, 101, 2)
                              ^
       error: class Range is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

There isn't any explanation from the instructor as to these types which appear to differ, and I'm struggling to understand why an error occurs in the newer version of Scala? Was the Range class previously not an abstract class? And if so, why was it changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking it in reverse, yes Scala 2.13 made `Range` abstract when it was previously concrete. However there was never any need to use `new` to create one because `val myRange2 = Range(1, 101, 2)` will work just fine, so this is an error in the tutorial.

The `to` method returns the type `Range.Inclusive` which is why this is printed by REPL. This is a subtype of `Range` so it has all the methods of `Range` and can be used wherever a `Range` can be used.

`new Range` returns `Range` because it is explicitly calling the constructor so it must return `Range`.

Note that if you do use `Range(1, 101, 2)` this will return `Range` in 2.12 and `Range.Exclusive` in 2.13.

Comment: TIL there's a factory `Range.inclusive`. They didn't take my advice to get rid of the subclass https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5226 There is no paper trail on the change for new collections at https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/909d28a66942c00ba4ff969f4513cebafa218318

Answer (score 2):

If you compare an [older `Range` Scaladocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.7/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html) (2.12.7 in this case) to the [current `Range` Scaladocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html) (2.13.1), you'll see that, yes, the `Range` class was changed to `abstract`. Not sure why. Collections went through a lot of changes with the 2.13 release.

As for the different `Range` type refinements, it's because `to` means `Inclusive`, which is not the default `Range` type.

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.7 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.6).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> 2 to 8
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range 2 to 8

scala> 2 until 9
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range 2 until 9

scala> Range(2, 9)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range 2 until 9
```

And there's been a further refinement in 2.13.

```
2 to 8      //res0: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range 2 to 8
2 until 9   //res1: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range 2 until 9
Range(2, 9) //res2: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Exclusive = Range 2 until 9
```